# Hardware needed to run the following PHP/MySQL/Linux System

Tags: php, mysql, linux, hardware

I developed a system to work with patients and stuff related to medical things.

In this case, the system has a MySQL database with 14 tables.

The table for doctor's appointments is going to record 50 appointments everyday. Then, the table for patient's record is gonna record 2000 entries every month.

There's also a message system, an agenda and some other little things. The system is gonna have, a very few users, like 15 or 20 everyday using it.

The company has a Dual Core AMD of almost 2.0 ghz with 4 GB RAM and 250 GB disk. ¿ Do you think is this hardware configuration enough ?. Or what is the recommended hardware for you point of view?.

The system is gonna run under Debian Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly better suited to [sf]... Check out their [faq](http://serverfault.com/faq) for more details on what is allowed there... [so] is for programming related questions.  Your question appears to be dealing only with hardware...

Comment: I say that's enough for such site.

Answer (score 0):

That's totally sufficient.

Our software specs (depending on customer):

```
- .NET
- 150 Tables
- Up to 1.000.000 records per Table
- 3-25 users
- about 5 connections per user
- database size 50 MB to 1.5 GB
```

it runs fine and fast with mysql on virtually any hardware we have installed in on. Even a Windows XP workstation with a single disk and 1GB RAM

It is more important to optimize your queries and setup some good startup values for MySQL.
Even if you notice some slowdown after a while (if you have more data) it is often easy to tweak the software to run fast again. And if that's not enough you can upgrade to a better machine in a year or two.

Comment: Thanks for the info. When you say "about 5 onnections per user", could you be more in depth to know how are these 5 connections?. Then, in my case, the system is web, and the 10 users are gonna connect to it. Im not sure if you application runs locally or its a server-side app with clients.

Comment: With 5 Connections I mean a the average "treads_connected" value / users. We monitor our mysql server and for 25 users we have about 150 threads connected. That is because a) users can start the app multiple times b) The app is stateless (create connection -> query -> close connection) like a webservice but uses a thread cache to improve connection creation. The connection count depends on your design but I would say it should be comparable (10 users times 5 connection equals 50 connections), that is nothing for a DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

When you make a query the time to return is divide, I read once something like this (not necessary the numbers but the order it's):

Hardware 10%

Design DB 30%

Query 60%

This is the time to response.  What this guy try to said is the query speed will depend a lot of how the programmer did the query what did he use and how did he use.
the Design is important too, be sure to use index where you need it,normalize, a EER design, check your buffer size, your cache, etc.

And for last, it's your hardware, after you had tune those two things you'll get the decision if your DB is really scalable or it can be improve just changing queries with `like '%variable%'`

Comment: Could you explain deeper what you meant with " it can be improve just changing queries with like '%variable%'". Thanks.